# Create custom QuerySet in Django

Tags: mysql, django, orm

I just created a custom QuerySet in Django, in which I've overridden the iterator function, because I need to exclude some object depending on a field value.

The problem is that the methods `values and values_list()` does not follow this solution, and using them I can bypass the custom filtering.

Can you give me some advice?

```
class LabeledQuerySet(QuerySet):
    def iterator(self):
        for x in QuerySet.iterator(self):
            if x.some_field==somevalue:
                yield x
```

Comment: can u share your custom queryset

Comment: class LabeledQuerySet(QuerySet):
        def iterator(self):
        
            for x in QuerySet.iterator(self):                      
                if x.some_field==somevalue:
                    yield x

Comment: Why do you filter the Query in Python after it already came from the database, instead of filtering it beforehand?

Comment: Cause my filtering is based on a label that it does not mapped in the database, so I need to retrieve object and only after I can purge objects! :-)

Comment: It seems you'll need to implement your own subclasses of `ValuesQuerySet` and `ValuesListQuerySet`, and override the `values` and `values_list` methods to return instances of your custom classes.